# Generate oauth signature for Flickr authentication using C#

Tags: c#, oauth, flickr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Invalid signature for signing requests to the Flickr API (simulation in console)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330004/invalid-signature-for-signing-requests-to-the-flickr-api-simulation-in-console)

I wanted to create a small Flickr app today but i'm stuck already at the beginning.

Here's the documentation I'm using:
http://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html

I end up with this url:

```
http://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/request_token?
oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com
&oauth_consumer_key=000000000000000000000000000000000000000
&oauth_nonce=89601180
&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1
&oauth_timestamp=1329405824
&oauth_version=1.0
```

But when i paste it into my browser i get the following response:

```
oauth_problem=parameter_absent&oauth_parameters_absent=oauth_signature
```

Seems that i should provide a oauth_signature parameter. but this is the parameter i want to generate with these url so i can use it to get my request_token.

I'm sure i'm doing something wrong here but i can't find what it is. Does someone knows more about this?

Thanks for your help!