# flickr oauth signature invalid error

Tags: c#

I am using OauthBase.cs class for generating the signature but am constantly getting an error saying that the signature is invalid. Could anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

I am temporarily displaying it in a message box and copying and pasting it in the browser to check it out.

Here's my code..

```
        string consumerKey = "consumer_key";
        string consumerSecret = "consumer_secret";

        string normalizedUrl = null;
        string normalizedRequestParameters = null;


        Uri url = new Uri("http://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/request_token");
        oAuthBase oAuth = new oAuthBase();

        string nonce = oAuth.GenerateNonce();
        string timeStamp = oAuth.GenerateTimeStamp();
        string callback = oAuth.UrlEncode("http://www.example.com");
        string sig = oAuth.GenerateSignature(url, consumerKey, consumerSecret, string.Empty   , string.Empty , "GET", timeStamp, nonce, callback , oAuthBase.SignatureTypes.HMACSHA1,out normalizedUrl ,out normalizedRequestParameters );
        sig = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(sig);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(url.ToString());


        sb.AppendFormat("?oauth_nonce={0}&", nonce);
        sb.AppendFormat("oauth_timestamp={0}&", timeStamp);
        sb.AppendFormat("oauth_consumer_key={0}&", consumerKey);
        sb.AppendFormat("oauth_signature_method={0}&", "HMAC-SHA1");           

        sb.AppendFormat("oauth_version={0}&", "1.0");

        sb.AppendFormat("oauth_signature={0}", sig);
        sb.AppendFormat("oauth_callback={0}", callback);


        MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Look at following thread. It may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330004/invalid-signature-for-signing-requests-to-the-flickr-api-simulation-in-console

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on the same thing since yesterday. No matter what i did i kept getting invalid_signature.

I then instead tried to use http://flickrnet.codeplex.com/, which works great. I can recommend that you use that. Or maybe look in the source code, prehaps that'll help you find the problem with your code.

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: flickrnet works but then my application size increases as i dont require all the classes listed in it, so i was trying with oAuthBase class instead.